# Why is the scanner not taking input when I run the code in intellij-idea but runs on eclipse

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have this problem that when I create a scanner in IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 16.3.2 it just gets stuck on waiting for input from the user. I hit enter or try to input anything in and it doesn't take it and, when I run the same code in eclipse it runs without any problems. So is this a problem I looked at there bug reports and found that there was a bug like that in version 9 and 10 but is it still there?

This is the code I have that I'm trying to run:

test case class:

```
public class GameLogicTest extends TestCase {
public void testBuyHouse() throws Exception {
    Player player = new Player(1000,0);
    GameboardSquare property = new GameboardSquare("Seb", 100,50,50,100,150,200,250,300,200,0,3,0,player,false);
    GameboardSquare[] gameboard = new GameboardSquare[1];
    gameboard[0] = property;
    GameLogic game = new GameLogic(gameboard);
    Board board = new Board(gameboard);
    board.setMonopolyBoard(gameboard);
    game.buyHouse(player,0);
}}
```

the code I'm tring to run/debug:

```
public class GameLogic extends Board {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public GameLogic(GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
    super(monopolyBoard);
}
public boolean buyHouse(Player player, int propertyIndex) {
  boolean boughtHouse = false;
  GameboardSquare property = getMonopolyBoard()[propertyIndex];
  if (property.getNumberHouse() <= 3) {
      System.out.println("How many houses you want to buy? it must be between 1-4: ");
      int numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println(numHouseToBuy);
      while (numHouseToBuy > 4) {
          System.out.println("To much to buy only 1-4");
          System.out.println("How many houses you want to buy? it must be between 1-4");
          numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
      }
      //think over the logic of the this switch statement
      switch (numHouseToBuy) {
          case 1:
              if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              } else {
                  //need to copy this to the other switch
                  System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                  System.out.println("You can only buy " + (4 - property.getNumberHouse()) );
                  numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
                  while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                      System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                      numHouseToBuy = toManyHouseOnPropertyError();
                  }
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              }
              break;
          case 2:
              if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - (property.getHouseCost() * 2));
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              } else {
                  System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                  numHouseToBuy = toManyHouseOnPropertyError();
                  while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                      System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                      numHouseToBuy = toManyHouseOnPropertyError();
                  }
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              }
              break;
          case 3:
              if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - (property.getHouseCost() * 3));
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              } else {
                  System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                  numHouseToBuy = toManyHouseOnPropertyError();
                  while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                      System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                      numHouseToBuy = toManyHouseOnPropertyError();
                  }
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              }
              break;
          case 4:
              if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - (property.getHouseCost() * 4));
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              } else {
                  System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                  System.out.println("You can only buy " + (4 - property.getNumberHouse()) );
                  numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
                  while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                      System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                      numHouseToBuy = toManyHouseOnPropertyError();
                  }
                  player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                  property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                  boughtHouse = true;
              }
              break;
          default:
              break;
      }
      return boughtHouse;
  } else {
      System.out.println("You own 4 houses on this property already");
      return boughtHouse;
  }}}
```

My other classes:

```
public class Board {
private GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard;
private Player player1;
private Player player2;
public Board(GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
    this.monopolyBoard = monopolyBoard;
}
//    public Board(){
////        monopolyBoard = new GameboardSquare[40];
//    }

public void setupGameBoard(File propertySquares) throws Exception{
    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    GameboardSquare a;
    while (input1.hasNextLine()){
        int index = 0;
        String property = input1.nextLine();
        String[] propertySqaure = property.split(",");
        // TODO: 11/15/2016 add other sqaure file some how
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                a = new GameboardSquare("Go",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,200,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 2:
                //community chest
                a = new GameboardSquare("Community Chest",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 4:
                //income tax
                break;
            case 7:
                //chance
                a = new GameboardSquare("Chance",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 10:
                //visit jail
                a = new GameboardSquare("Just Visiting Jail",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 17:
                //community chest
                a = new GameboardSquare("Community Chest",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 20:
                //free parking
                a = new GameboardSquare("Free Parking",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 22:
                //chance
                a = new GameboardSquare("Chance",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 40:
                //go to jail
                a = new GameboardSquare("Go To Jail",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 43:
                //community chest
                a = new GameboardSquare("Community Chest",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 46:
                ///chance
                a = new GameboardSquare("Chance",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null,false);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
            case 48:
                //luxury tax
                break;
            default:
                a = parseMethod(propertySqaure);
                monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public GameboardSquare parseMethod(String[] propertySqaure) {
    String propertyName = propertySqaure[0];
    int value = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[1]);
    int rent = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[3]);
    int rent1 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[4]);
    int rent2 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[5]);
    int rent3 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[6]);
    int rent4 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[7]);
    int hotel = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[8]);
    int mortgage = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[9]);
    int houseCost = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[2]);
//        int hotelCost = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[2]);
    int moneyGive = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[10]);
    Player owner = null;
    GameboardSquare a = new             GameboardSquare(propertyName,value,houseCost,rent,rent1,rent2,rent3,rent4,hotel,    mortgage, moneyGive,0,0,owner, false);
    return a;
}

public GameboardSquare[] getMonopolyBoard() {
    return monopolyBoard;
}

public Player getPlayer1() {
    return player1;
}

public void setPlayer1(Player player) {
    this.player1 = player;
}

public Player getPlayer2() {
    return player2;
}

public void setPlayer2(Player player2) {
    this.player2 = player2;
}

public void setMonopolyBoard(GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
    this.monopolyBoard = monopolyBoard;
}}
```

Player:

```
public class Player {
private int currentMoney;
private int moveIndex;

public Player(int currentMoney, int moveIndex) {
    this.moveIndex = moveIndex;
    this.currentMoney = currentMoney;
}


public void moves(Player player, int moves) {
    int a = player.getMoveIndex() + moves;
    if (a > 41) {
        int b = a - 40;
        player.setMoveIndex(b);
        if (player.getMoveIndex() != 0) {
            player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() + 200);
        }
    } else {
        player.setMoveIndex(a);
    }
}

public void rollsDie(Dice die1, Dice die2) {
    int max = 6;
    int min = 1;
    //rolls the diecs and set the die resules
    //returnes the dies reslues //idk
    Random rand = new Random();
    int value = rand.nextInt(50);
//        This will give value from 0 to 49.
//        For 1 to 50: 
    die1.setDie(rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);
    die2.setDie(rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min);
}

public int getcurrentMoney() {
    return currentMoney;
}

public void setcurrentMoney(int currentMoney) {
    this.currentMoney = currentMoney;
}

public int getMoveIndex() {
    return moveIndex;
}

public void setMoveIndex(int moveIndex) {
    this.moveIndex = moveIndex;
}}
```

GameSquare:

```
public class GameboardSquare {
private String squareName;
private int cost;
private int hotel;
private int rent;
private int moneyGive;
private int rent1;
private int rent2;
private int rent3;
private int rent4;
private int mortgage;
private int houseCost;
private int hotelCost;
private int numberHouse;
private int numberHotels;
private boolean hasMortgage;
private Player propertyOwner;

//todo add player owns var and player mortgage var
public GameboardSquare(String squareName, int cost, int houseCost, int rent, int rent1, int rent2, int rent3,
                       int rent4, int hotel, int mortgage, int moneyGive, int numberHouse, int numberHotels, Player owner, boolean hasMortgage) {
    this.squareName = squareName;
    this.cost = cost;
    this.hotel = hotel;
    this.rent = rent;
    this.moneyGive = moneyGive;
    this.rent1 = rent1;
    this.rent2 = rent2;
    this.rent3 = rent3;
    this.rent4 = rent4;
    this.mortgage = mortgage;
    this.houseCost = houseCost;
    this.numberHouse = numberHouse;
    this.numberHotels = numberHotels;
    this.hasMortgage = hasMortgage;
    this.propertyOwner = owner;//// TODO: 11/15/2016 make a more specific
}

public boolean hasHouse(Player player, GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
    return monopolyBoard[player.getMoveIndex()].getNumberHouse() > 0;
}

public boolean hasHotel(Player player, GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
    return monopolyBoard[player.getMoveIndex()].getNumberHotels() > 0;
}

public String getSquareName() {
    return squareName;
}

public void setSquareName(String squareName) {
    this.squareName = squareName;
}

public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}

public void setCost(int cost) {
    this.cost = cost;
}

public int getHotel() {
    return hotel;
}

public void setHotel(int hotel) {
    this.hotel = hotel;
}

public int getRent() {
    return rent;
}

public void setRent(int rent) {
    this.rent = rent;
}

public int getMoneyGive() {
    return moneyGive;
}

public void setMoneyGive(int moneyGive) {
    this.moneyGive = moneyGive;
}

public int getRent1() {
    return rent1;
}

public void setRent1(int rent1) {
    this.rent1 = rent1;
}

public int getRent2() {
    return rent2;
}

public void setRent2(int rent2) {
    this.rent2 = rent2;
}

public int getRent3() {
    return rent3;
}

public void setRent3(int rent3) {
    this.rent3 = rent3;
}

public int getRent4() {
    return rent4;
}

public void setRent4(int rent4) {
    this.rent4 = rent4;
}

public int getMortgage() {
    return mortgage;
}

public void setMortgage(int mortgage) {
    this.mortgage = mortgage;
}

public int getHouseCost() {
    return houseCost;
}

public void setHouseCost(int houseCost) {
    this.houseCost = houseCost;
}

public int getHotelCost() {
    return hotelCost;
}

public void setHotelCost(int hotelCost) {
    this.hotelCost = hotelCost;
}

public int getNumberHouse() {
    return numberHouse;
}

public void setNumberHouse(int numberHouse) {
    this.numberHouse = numberHouse;
}

public int getNumberHotels() {
    return numberHotels;
}

public void setNumberHotels(int numberHotels) {
    this.numberHotels = numberHotels;
}

public boolean isHasMortgage() {
    return hasMortgage;
}

public void setHasMortgage(boolean hasMortgage) {
    this.hasMortgage = hasMortgage;
}

public Player getPropertyOwner() {
    return propertyOwner;
}

public void setPropertyOwner(Player propertyOwner) {
    this.propertyOwner = propertyOwner;
}}
```

some screen shots 
intellij:
[intellij picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lScDr.png)

eclipse: before entering input: [eclipse picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNUIF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it with IntelliJ Ultimate Edition and it was possible to buy 1 house.

```
How many houses you want to buy? it must be between 1-4: 
1
1
boughtHouse
```

Code with small changes below.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().testBuyHouse();
    }

    public void testBuyHouse() {
        Player player = new Player(1000000, 0);
        GameboardSquare property = new GameboardSquare("Seb", 100, 50, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 200, 0, 3, 0, player, false);
        GameboardSquare[] gameboard = new GameboardSquare[3];
        gameboard[0] = property;
        GameLogic game = new GameLogic(gameboard);
        Board board = new Board(gameboard);
        board.setMonopolyBoard(gameboard);
        game.buyHouse(player, 0);
    }
}

class GameLogic extends Board {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public GameLogic(GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
        super(monopolyBoard);
    }

    public boolean buyHouse(Player player, int propertyIndex) {
        boolean boughtHouse = false;
        GameboardSquare property = getMonopolyBoard()[propertyIndex];
        if (property.getNumberHouse() <= 3) {
            System.out.println("How many houses you want to buy? it must be between 1-4: ");
            int numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println(numHouseToBuy);
            while (numHouseToBuy > 4) {
                System.out.println("To much to buy only 1-4");
                System.out.println("How many houses you want to buy? it must be between 1-4");
                numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
            }
            //think over the logic of the this switch statement
            switch (numHouseToBuy) {
                case 1:
                    if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                        System.out.println("boughtHouse");
                    } else {
                        //need to copy this to the other switch
                        System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                        System.out.println("You can only buy " + (4 - property.getNumberHouse()));
                        numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
                        while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                            System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                            numHouseToBuy = 4;
                        }
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - (property.getHouseCost() * 2));
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                        numHouseToBuy = 4;
                        while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                            System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                            numHouseToBuy = 4;
                        }
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - (property.getHouseCost() * 3));
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                        numHouseToBuy = 4;
                        while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                            System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                            numHouseToBuy = 4;
                        }
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() <= 4) {
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - (property.getHouseCost() * 4));
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                        System.out.println("You can only buy " + (4 - property.getNumberHouse()));
                        numHouseToBuy = input.nextInt();
                        while (numHouseToBuy + property.getNumberHouse() > 4) {
                            System.out.println("To many houses on this property");
                            numHouseToBuy = 4;
                        }
                        player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() - property.getHouseCost());
                        property.setNumberHouse(property.getNumberHouse() + numHouseToBuy);
                        boughtHouse = true;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            return boughtHouse;
        } else {
            System.out.println("You own 4 houses on this property already");
            return boughtHouse;
        }
    }
}

class Board {
    private GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard;
    private Player player1;
    private Player player2;

    Board(GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
        this.monopolyBoard = monopolyBoard;
    }
//    public Board(){
////        monopolyBoard = new GameboardSquare[40];
//    }

    public void setupGameBoard(File propertySquares) throws Exception {
        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        GameboardSquare a;
        while (input1.hasNextLine()) {
            int index = 0;
            String property = input1.nextLine();
            String[] propertySqaure = property.split(",");
            // TODO: 11/15/2016 add other sqaure file some how
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Go", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 200, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //community chest
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Community Chest", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //income tax
                    break;
                case 7:
                    //chance
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Chance", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 10:
                    //visit jail
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Just Visiting Jail", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 17:
                    //community chest
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Community Chest", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 20:
                    //free parking
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Free Parking", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 22:
                    //chance
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Chance", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 40:
                    //go to jail
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Go To Jail", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 43:
                    //community chest
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Community Chest", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 46:
                    ///chance
                    a = new GameboardSquare("Chance", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, null, false);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
                case 48:
                    //luxury tax
                    break;
                default:
                    a = parseMethod(propertySqaure);
                    monopolyBoard[index++] = a;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    GameboardSquare parseMethod(String[] propertySqaure) {
        String propertyName = propertySqaure[0];
        int value = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[1]);
        int rent = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[3]);
        int rent1 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[4]);
        int rent2 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[5]);
        int rent3 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[6]);
        int rent4 = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[7]);
        int hotel = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[8]);
        int mortgage = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[9]);
        int houseCost = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[2]);
//        int hotelCost = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[2]);
        int moneyGive = Integer.parseInt(propertySqaure[10]);
        Player owner = null;
        GameboardSquare a = new GameboardSquare(propertyName, value, houseCost, rent, rent1, rent2, rent3, rent4, hotel, mortgage, moneyGive, 0, 0, owner, false);
        return a;
    }

    GameboardSquare[] getMonopolyBoard() {
        return monopolyBoard;
    }

    public Player getPlayer1() {
        return player1;
    }

    public void setPlayer1(Player player) {
        this.player1 = player;
    }

    public Player getPlayer2() {
        return player2;
    }

    public void setPlayer2(Player player2) {
        this.player2 = player2;
    }

    public void setMonopolyBoard(GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
        this.monopolyBoard = monopolyBoard;
    }
}


class Player {
    private int currentMoney;
    private int moveIndex;

    public Player(int currentMoney, int moveIndex) {
        this.moveIndex = moveIndex;
        this.currentMoney = currentMoney;
    }


    public void moves(Player player, int moves) {
        int a = player.getMoveIndex() + moves;
        if (a > 41) {
            int b = a - 40;
            player.setMoveIndex(b);
            if (player.getMoveIndex() != 0) {
                player.setcurrentMoney(player.getcurrentMoney() + 200);
            }
        } else {
            player.setMoveIndex(a);
        }
    }


    public int getcurrentMoney() {
        return currentMoney;
    }

    public void setcurrentMoney(int currentMoney) {
        this.currentMoney = currentMoney;
    }

    public int getMoveIndex() {
        return moveIndex;
    }

    public void setMoveIndex(int moveIndex) {
        this.moveIndex = moveIndex;
    }
}

class GameboardSquare {
    private String squareName;
    private int cost;
    private int hotel;
    private int rent;
    private int moneyGive;
    private int rent1;
    private int rent2;
    private int rent3;
    private int rent4;
    private int mortgage;
    private int houseCost;
    private int hotelCost;
    private int numberHouse;
    private int numberHotels;
    private boolean hasMortgage;
    private Player propertyOwner;

    //todo add player owns var and player mortgage var
    GameboardSquare(String squareName, int cost, int houseCost, int rent, int rent1, int rent2, int rent3,
                    int rent4, int hotel, int mortgage, int moneyGive, int numberHouse, int numberHotels, Player owner, boolean hasMortgage) {
        this.squareName = squareName;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.hotel = hotel;
        this.rent = rent;
        this.moneyGive = moneyGive;
        this.rent1 = rent1;
        this.rent2 = rent2;
        this.rent3 = rent3;
        this.rent4 = rent4;
        this.mortgage = mortgage;
        this.houseCost = houseCost;
        this.numberHouse = numberHouse;
        this.numberHotels = numberHotels;
        this.hasMortgage = hasMortgage;
        this.propertyOwner = owner;//// TODO: 11/15/2016 make a more specific
    }

    public boolean hasHouse(Player player, GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
        return monopolyBoard[player.getMoveIndex()].getNumberHouse() > 0;
    }

    public boolean hasHotel(Player player, GameboardSquare[] monopolyBoard) {
        return monopolyBoard[player.getMoveIndex()].getNumberHotels() > 0;
    }

    public String getSquareName() {
        return squareName;
    }

    public void setSquareName(String squareName) {
        this.squareName = squareName;
    }

    public int getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(int cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public int getHotel() {
        return hotel;
    }

    public void setHotel(int hotel) {
        this.hotel = hotel;
    }

    public int getRent() {
        return rent;
    }

    public void setRent(int rent) {
        this.rent = rent;
    }

    public int getMoneyGive() {
        return moneyGive;
    }

    public void setMoneyGive(int moneyGive) {
        this.moneyGive = moneyGive;
    }

    public int getRent1() {
        return rent1;
    }

    public void setRent1(int rent1) {
        this.rent1 = rent1;
    }

    public int getRent2() {
        return rent2;
    }

    public void setRent2(int rent2) {
        this.rent2 = rent2;
    }

    public int getRent3() {
        return rent3;
    }

    public void setRent3(int rent3) {
        this.rent3 = rent3;
    }

    public int getRent4() {
        return rent4;
    }

    public void setRent4(int rent4) {
        this.rent4 = rent4;
    }

    public int getMortgage() {
        return mortgage;
    }

    public void setMortgage(int mortgage) {
        this.mortgage = mortgage;
    }

    public int getHouseCost() {
        return houseCost;
    }

    public void setHouseCost(int houseCost) {
        this.houseCost = houseCost;
    }

    public int getHotelCost() {
        return hotelCost;
    }

    public void setHotelCost(int hotelCost) {
        this.hotelCost = hotelCost;
    }

    public int getNumberHouse() {
        return numberHouse;
    }

    public void setNumberHouse(int numberHouse) {
        this.numberHouse = numberHouse;
    }

    public int getNumberHotels() {
        return numberHotels;
    }

    public void setNumberHotels(int numberHotels) {
        this.numberHotels = numberHotels;
    }

    public boolean isHasMortgage() {
        return hasMortgage;
    }

    public void setHasMortgage(boolean hasMortgage) {
        this.hasMortgage = hasMortgage;
    }

    public Player getPropertyOwner() {
        return propertyOwner;
    }

    public void setPropertyOwner(Player propertyOwner) {
        this.propertyOwner = propertyOwner;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you put all the classes into one class file.

Comment: @Seba13xp We can try your exact configuration but that will take more time. You could also try your code without an IDE and just build from command line?

Comment: @ Dac Saunders if its no trouble then ya, if not then its ok and thank you for helping.